# Html.ActionLink Fires on Load Unintentionally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, onload, actionlink, html.actionlink

I have a Partial View for showing the list of products. In this view I have  ActionLinks above each column to handle sorting. There are total 4 of them and they are all identical to below one:

```
 <div class="col-xs-2">
    @Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ProductName).ToHtmlString(), "Products", AppendQueryString.AppendQuery("sortOrder", ViewData["ProductNameSort"].ToString()))
</div>
```

In order to be able to append the current URL without losing any previously querystrings, I created a static class AppendQueryString and a method in it called AppendQuery. The class looks like below:

```
 public static RouteValueDictionary AppendQuery(string key, string value)
    {
        RouteValueDictionary routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        var req = context.Request.QueryString;

        foreach (string qkey in req)
        {
            routeValues[qkey] = req[qkey];
        }

        if (!routeValues.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            routeValues.Add(key, value);
        }
        else
        {
            routeValues.Remove(key);
            routeValues.Add(key, value);
        }

        return routeValues;
    }
```

First I didn't realize what was the problem but something was trying to rewrite the same key value sent into this method so I had to use that ugly if-else there to add the key-value into the RouteValueDictionary properly and continue on with the project.

However, now the problem is obvious that for some reason, on page loading these four ActionLinks I have are being fired one after another so the AppendQuery method is being called 4 times on page load. The main View that renders this partial view is being called only once I am sure about it. Any of you have any idea why is this happening ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you add link four times it will call method four times and it’s expected behavior. What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Is there any way to stop execution of links on page load and restrict them to fire only when they are clicked ? Because this doesn't look like a healthy behavior.

Comment: are you saying the page is redirecting to those link pages ?

Comment: No its not. but calls the method many times. But I think i figured the problem out. Actually it is trying to create the "href" link for those ActionLink elements on page load. Ok now i see. I was trying to figure if there is any way to go around it but. May not be necessary.

Comment: That’s what I said call the method once and assign it

Comment: I am a little new to this MVC stuff so I was trying to understand if there is a problem. Seems like there isn't right now :) Thank you for letting me know it is natural behavior.